# How to count from two fields in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56bd8e9de517259412a743ab"),
    "user_token" : "mzXhdbCu",
    "sender_details" : {
        "location" : "XYZ",
        "zipcode" : "610208"
    },
    "shipping_address" : {
        "location" : "ABC",
        "zipcode" : "602578
    }
}
```

I have been trying to count the number of instances of each unique zipcode from both

```
$sender_details.zipcode
```

and

```
$shipping_address.zipcode
```

I tried to use the following code

```
db.ac_consignments.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: {
            "zipcode":"$sender_details.zipcode", 
            "szipcode":"$shipping_address.zipcode"
        }, 
        count: {"$sum":1}
    }
})
```

The output I receive is this

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "zipcode" : "610208",
                "szipcode" : "602578"
            },
            "count" : 7
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "zipcode" : "602578",
                "szipcode" : "678705"
            },
            "count" : 51
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

But what I require is the count of each zipcode present in `$sender_details.zipcode` and `$shipping_address.zipcode` totally. So an output like this

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "zipcode" : "610208",
            },
            "count" : 7
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "zipcode" : "602578"
            },
            "count" : 51
        }
        {
            "_id" : {
                "zipcode" : "678705"
            },
            "count" : 51
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following pipeline should work for you

```
db.getCollection('ac_consignments').aggregate([
    {       
        $project: {
            zipcode: [ "$sender_details.zipcode", "$shipping_address.zipcode" ]
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$zipcode"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$zipcode",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

which produces output like this

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "610208",
    "count" : 1.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "610209",
    "count" : 2.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "602578",
    "count" : 1.0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "602579",
    "count" : 2.0
}
```

when using the following as sample data

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56bd8e9de517259412a743ab"),
    "user_token" : "mzXhdbCu",
    "sender_details" : {
        "location" : "XYZ",
        "zipcode" : "610208"
    },
    "shipping_address" : {
        "location" : "ABC",
        "zipcode" : "602578"
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56bd8e9de517259412a743ac"),
    "user_token" : "mzXhdbCu",
    "sender_details" : {
        "location" : "XYZ",
        "zipcode" : "610209"
    },
    "shipping_address" : {
        "location" : "ABC",
        "zipcode" : "602579"
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56bd8e9de517259412a753ac"),
    "user_token" : "mzXhdbCu",
    "sender_details" : {
        "location" : "XYZ",
        "zipcode" : "610209"
    },
    "shipping_address" : {
        "location" : "ABC",
        "zipcode" : "602579"
    }
}
```

---

See the following GIF

[image: GIF showing pipeline in action]

---

**Update for older versions**

```
db.getCollection('ac_consignments').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            sender_zip: "$sender_details.zipcode",
            shipping_zip: "$shipping_address.zipcode",
            party: { $literal: ["sender_zip", "shipping_zip"] }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$party"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            zipcode: {
                $push: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $eq: ["$party", "sender_zip"] },
                        "$sender_zip",
                        "$shipping_zip"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$zipcode"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$zipcode",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: There seems to be an error when I try to run the code:         Error("Printing Stack Trace")@:0
()@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37
([object Array])@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:866
@(shell):15

uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: disallowed field type Array in object expression (at 'zipcode')",
 "code" : 15992,
 "ok" : 0
}

Comment: What version of mongoDB are you using, as the projecting into an array is new in version 3.2 which my pipeline requires

Comment: mongoDB version is 2.0.4

Comment: It seems to be working on yours. But not mine. I'm using robomongo 0.8.4.

Comment: Yeah as mentioned in my comment it requires a somewhat current release >= 3.2. mongoDB 2.0.4 is a bit old :) Anyway I try to figure out a way for 2.0.4 as I guess upgrading is not that easy for you right now ?! :)

Comment: yes. Its not easy to upgrade right now. It would be of great help if you could find a solution to this that is compatible with 2.0.4. I know its not easy. I have been at this for hours now. :)

Comment: Please check my alternative solution - I could not test it myself as I do not have a 2.0.4 mongoDB instance running here so it may still fail but I hope all the used operators are available. If not I will have a look at it tonight when I am at home and can work with my homelab :)

Comment: There seems to be some error again. This time with the use of $unwind:   uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: the $unwind field path must be specified as a string",
 "code" : 15981,
 "ok" : 0
} .... Thank you for taking your time to help me with this

Comment: Ok next try - seems that $unwind in older versions accept only a string and not an object literal. See the updated answer with a slightly different $unwind stage. I am sure at some point we will have it :D

Comment: Thank you once again. Its been a pleasure :D